# Is there an easier way to convert an int to unicode?

Tags: javascript, unicode

I'm currently doing a big switch statement in my javascript to convert

```
            case 176: char = '\u00B0'; break;
            case 177: char = '\u00B1'; break;
            case 178: char = '\u00B2'; break;
            case 179: char = '\u00B3'; break;
            case 180: char = '\u00B4'; break;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if your variable is named `intVar` you could use ...

```
var stringVar = String.fromCharCode(intVar);
```

... to get the unicode character.

Comment: `String.fromCharCode(intVar)` won’t work for supplementary Unicode characters. If `intVar` is `119558` (`0x1D306`, for the `''` character), for example. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9109467/96656) for a solution that works for any code point.

Comment: I want to convert hexadecimal number like 
var i = 0x1F64F;
To its equivalent emosy symbol 
see http://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect/hex/1F64F

Answer (score 4):

[JavaScript uses UCS-2 internally.](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-encoding)

Thus, `String.fromCharCode(intVar)` won’t work for supplementary Unicode characters. If `intVar` is `119558` (`0x1D306`, for the `''` character), for example.

If you want to create a string based on a non-BMP Unicode code point, you could use [Punycode.js](http://mths.be/punycode)’s utility functions to convert between UCS-2 strings and UTF-16 code points:

```
// `String.fromCharCode` replacement that doesn’t make you enter the surrogate halves separately
punycode.ucs2.encode([0x1d306]); // ''
punycode.ucs2.encode([119558]); // ''
punycode.ucs2.encode([97, 98, 99]); // 'abc'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `String.fromCharCode(i)`. Note that arguments are expected to be UTF-16 encoded values. See [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf) chapter 15.5.3.2 for details.